# Remote connection to Hadoop namenode issue

Tags: ssh, hadoop

I am required to hack a single node hadoop "cluster" (cloudera psuedo-distributed) to be able to access it remotely.  I have successfully installed hadoop and I have updated the localhost identifiers in the configs to the IP address of the machine.  I can run `hadoop fs -ls /` and all is good.  I have created a passphraseless key and I can ssh to the hadoop machine.

The connection is established with:

```
ssh -vvvv -i .ssh/hadoop_rsa -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ServerAliveInterval=60 -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null-N -D 6666 parkerro@151.84.13.73
```

When I run `hadoop fs -ls /` on the remote machine, the ssh output is:

```
debug1: Connection to port 6666 forwarding to socks port 0 requested.
debug2: fd 6 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug2: fd 6 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: fd 6 is O_NONBLOCK
debug1: channel 2: new [dynamic-tcpip]
debug2: channel 2: pre_dynamic: have 0
debug2: channel 2: pre_dynamic: have 4
debug2: channel 2: decode socks5
debug2: channel 2: socks5 auth done
debug2: channel 2: pre_dynamic: need more
debug2: channel 2: pre_dynamic: have 0
debug2: channel 2: pre_dynamic: have 10
debug2: channel 2: decode socks5
debug2: channel 2: socks5 post auth
debug2: channel 2: dynamic request: socks5 host 151.84.13.73 port 8020 command 1
channel 2: open failed: administratively prohibited: open failed
debug2: channel 2: zombie
debug2: channel 2: garbage collecting
debug1: channel 2: free: direct-tcpip: listening port 6666 for 151.84.13.73 port 8020, connect from 127.0.0.1 port 50703, nchannels 3
debug3: channel 2: status: The following connections are open:
```

Focusing on the `administratively prohibited` I have ensured the ports 8020 and 8021 are open on the hadoop machine (151.84.13.73)

```
sudo ufw status
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
munin-node                 ALLOW       Anywhere
5666/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere
8021                       ALLOW       Anywhere
8020                       ALLOW       Anywhere
```

and

```
sudo iptables -L 
.
.
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp dpt:8021 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:8020 
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp dpt:8020 





.
```

What would be other reasons for `channel 2: open failed`?

Edit 1:
It appears that hadoop is listening on the correct ports:

```
.netstat -ant

Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:4949            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:25              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5666            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 151.84.13.73:22        10.10.42.74:54777       ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 151.84.13.73:38547     15.184.32.197:5667      TIME_WAIT
tcp        0      0 151.84.13.73:38549     15.184.32.197:5667      TIME_WAIT
tcp        0      0 151.84.13.73:55729     15.185.12.213:636       ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 151.84.13.73:22        15.184.4.3:56649        ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 151.84.13.73:55727     15.185.12.213:636       ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 151.84.13.73:55728     15.185.12.213:636       ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 151.84.13.73:55834     15.185.12.213:636       ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 151.84.13.73:38548     15.184.32.197:5667      TIME_WAIT
tcp        0      0 151.84.13.73:55835     15.185.12.213:636       ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 151.84.13.73:8020      :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 151.84.13.73:8021      :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::50070                :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::35574                :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::50010                :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::50075                :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::50020                :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::34340                :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:59241         :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::50090                :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::50060                :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::54956                :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::35725                :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::50030                :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 151.84.13.73:8021      151.84.13.73:46151     ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 151.84.13.73:46151     151.84.13.73:8021      ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 151.84.13.73:8020      151.84.13.73:45886     ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 151.84.13.73:45886     151.84.13.73:8020      ESTABLISHED
```

and nmap shows both the ports open.

Is there any other authentication going on?